# PHP switch is not working

Tags: php

I have made a calculator in PHP using POST and two params - `num1` and `num2`. But when I want to calculates the numbers the answer is not showing.
What should I do?

Here is my code:

```php
if ($_POST) {
    $first_number = $_POST['first_number'];
    $second_number = $_POST['second_number'];
    $cal = $_POST['cal'];

    switch ('$cal') {
        case "Addition":
            $result = $first_number + $second_number;
            break;
        case "Subtraction":
            $result = $first_number - $second_number;
            break;
        case "Multiplication":
            $result = $first_number * $second_number;
            break;
        case "Division":
            $result = $first_number / $second_number;
            break;
        case "Modulation":
            $result = $first_number % $second_number;
            break;
    }
    return $result;
}
echo "$cal <br /> <br /> 1st Number: $first_number <br /> 2nd Number: $second_number <br /><br />";
echo "Answer is:" . $result;
```

Comment: Remove quotes from switch ('$cal') --> switch ($cal)

Comment: If that worked for you, then you can mark it as answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove quotes from your switch statement

Replace

```
switch ('$cal')
```

With

```
switch ($cal)
```